# Spring Boot @Scheduled with @PreDestory method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have a component that looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ExampleComponent {

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1)
  public void scheduledTask() {
    // process
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    // shutdown
  }
}
```

I want to execute some code when the application shuts down. However, the `shutdown` method is called before the `@Scheduled` task is completed. How to I get `shutdown` to await for the `@Scheduled` method to be finished, or how to I get it to terminate it?

I've tried adding these configurations with no luck:

```
spring:
  task:
    scheduling:
      shutdown:
        await-termination: true
        await-termination-period: 30S
    execution:
      shutdown:
        await-termination: true
        await-termination-period: 30S
```

Comment: Are you closing instance of `ConfigurableApplicationContext` in your shutdown() method. ? It's recommended to call close() method directly using the application context.

Comment: Why do I need to close the ApplicationContext? The application shutdown process starts when the process is interrupted.

Comment: Just to release resources / perform cleanup tasks before the bean gets destroyed. Also @PreDestroy annotations is a part of Java EE, and since Java EE has been deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11, We need to add 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: I've already added that as a dependency.

Comment: For `@Scheduled` annotation to work, Have you added `@EnableScheduling` annotation ?